# Hash Table vs Dictionary

Tags: data-structures

As far as I know hash table uses has key to store any item whereas dictionary uses simple key value pair to store item.it means that dictionary is a lot faster than hash table (Which I think. Please correct me if I am wrong).
**Does this mean I should never use hash table?**

Comment: *"..it means that dictionary is a lot faster than hash table.."* - In this business, we don't conclude on "X is faster than Y" without empirical evidence... Where is yours?

Comment: Because to search a item in a hash table it first computes the hash key and then finds the required item where as in dictionary we can simply get the value by entering key.Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @user7190448 As one example where your statement is questionable, consider .NET `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. It's implemented as a hash table. How do you think most dictionaries "simply get the value"? ;)

Comment: Okay, so dictionary what we are using in C# internally uses hash table to store the data??

Comment: Yes. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks and http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0

Comment: @jdphenix thanks a lot ,i got the answer,

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends".

A Dictionary is merely a way to map a key to a value.  You can either use a library or implement one yourself.

A Hash table is a specific way to implement a dictionary where the key based upon a hash function.  This function is usually based on modulo arithmetic.  This means that two distinct value may end up with the hash key and therefore there will be a collision between the keys.  It is then up to you (or whoever implements the hash table) to the determine how to resolve the collision.  You could chain the value at the same key, re-hash and use a sub-hash table, or you may even want to start over with a new hash function (which would be expensive).

Depending on the underlying implementation of the dictionary (hash table) will affect your lookup performance.